# Android - listen to changes in a folder

Tags: android

I have a Bluetooth application, which will list out all of the files in the bluetooth folder on my phone. So far I have only done it this way:

```
public class GetCaseInformation {

int numberOfFiles;
String pathToFolder;
File folder;

public GetCaseInformation(String pathToFolder) {

    this.pathToFolder = pathToFolder; 
    folder = new File(pathToFolder);
}


public int getCasesFromFolder() {

    return folder.list().length; 

}

}
```

A very simple way to check how many files I have in my folder. The method `getCasesFromFolder()` is called in my `onCreate` method, so this will just be updated every time the user goes to the home screen. Is it possible to listen for changes in a spesific folder? So I dynamicaly can update the count of files in this folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `FileObserver`:

> Monitors files (using inotify) to fire an event after files are
>   accessed or changed by by any process on the device (including this
>   one). FileObserver is an abstract class; subclasses must implement the
>   event handler onEvent(int, String).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Docs say: "Each FileObserver instance monitors a single file or **directory**. If a directory is monitored, events will be triggered for all files and subdirectories inside the monitored directory."